# How to bind dataSet changes from DataGRiwView to the parents node in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, dataset

i have an xml config file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
  <FirstNode>
    <FirstNodeChild attr="one" Path="www"  />
    <FirstNodeChild attr="two" Path="aaa"  />
    <FirstNodeChild attr="three" Path="zzz"  />
  </FirstNode>

  <SecondNode>
    <SecondNodeChild attr="one"  Path="ttt"  />
    <SecondNodeChild attr="two"  Path="yyy"  />
    <SecondNodeChild attr="three" Path="uuu"  />
  </SecondNode>
</config>
```

Using dataSet, i can display the part i need in a dataGridView

```
dataset = new DataSet();         
dataset.ReadXml(//path);
MyGrid.DataSource = dataset.Tables["SecondNodeChild"];
MyGrid.AllowUserToAddrows = true;
MyGrid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
```

I added a button to save any changes: delete, creation or update.

```
private void SaveChangesBtn_Click(obj sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataset.Tables["SecondNodeChild"].AcceptChanges();
   dataset.WriteXml(//path);
}
```

It works for updating or deleting already existing FirstNodeChilds.
But when i want to create a new row :

```
...<SecondNode>
    <SecondNodeChild attr="one"  Path="ttt"  />
    <SecondNodeChild attr="two"  Path="yyy"  />
    <SecondNodeChild attr="three" Path="uuu"  />
  </SecondNode>
    <SecondNodeChild attr="four" Path="nnn"  />
</config>
```

Is there a way to bind it to the parents node (SecondNode here)?

Without using xmlDocument, XmlNode , AppendChild etc to get all input.Texts using another button.

Comment: `AcceptChanges` marks everything as unchanged, which might be fine if you are just writing to xml, but see if there is a difference if you do `WriteXml` before `AcceptChanges`.

Comment: Good question.  A common problem with method in Net library to bind XML elements. You have to write you own code to link the DataTable Row to an XML element.

Comment: @Crowcoder ahah i see, before, after or without, same result.

Comment: @ydre not surprised in this case, but definitely do not AcceptChanges when binding to a database unless you want to undo user input.